# PSEXEC wont run exe

Tags: remote-access, remote-control, psexec

I am trying to execute an exe on a remote machine with PSEXEC but it wont run.

It only works if I spawn a CMD window with PSEXEC and execute the .exe that way:

```
PSEXEC.exe \\<machine_name> cmd
cd <path_to_folder>
.\<exe_name> <parameter>
```

The file gets executed just fine on the remote machine.

But if I run `PSEXEC.exe \\<machine_name> "<path_to_folder>\<exe_name>" <parameter>` I get a wait cursor for 15 secs and the session ends.
But nothing happend on the remote machine.

On the remote machine I ran PROCMON and saw the exe getting called and even saw my PSEXEC command, but the exe did nothing.

This is so confusing... I need to run multiple PSEXEC sessions so prefer the "one-liner" method.

Comment: Try `PSEXEC.exe \\<machine_name> cmd /c "drive:/path/exe_name.exe" [parameters]`

Comment: @Akina Hi, I have the same result.